# Unable to obtain embedded recipient view from DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

I have integrated DocuSign embedded signing into my web app, which is still in development so using DocuSign developer sandbox.

When an envelope is created programmatically, I am including Name, Email and ClientUserId for the signer like this:

```cs
var signers = new List<TemplateRole>();
foreach (var r in req.Recipients)
{
    var signer = new TemplateRole();
    signer.ClientUserId = r.SSOUserId;
    signer.Email = r.Email;
    signer.Name = r.Name;
    signer.RoleName = r.RoleName;
    signer.RoutingOrder = r.RoutingOrder.ToString();
    signer.Tabs = r.MergeFields
    signers.Add(signer);
}

var env = new EnvelopeDefinition() 
{
    TemplateId = ...,
    TemplateRoles = new List<TemplateRole>(signers),
    EventNotification = ...,
    Status = "Sent"
};
```

When an embedded recipient view is requested, I include the same exact Name, Email and ClientUserId in the request like this:

```cs
var envelopeApi = new EnvelopesApi(ApiClient);
var viewOptions = new RecipientViewRequest
{
    ReturnUrl = ...,
    AuthenticationMethod = "Password",
    ClientUserId = recipient.SSOUserId,
    UserName = recipient.Name,
    Email = recipient.Email
};
var viewUrl = envelopeApi.CreateRecipientView(AccountId, DocuSignEnvelopeId, viewOptions);
```

Even though the user may change their Name and/or Email in my app, I have the original values saved in a table and I use those original values when requesting the view from DocuSign. This setup has worked 100% of the time for many months until now when an envelope is having trouble obtaining a recipient view. The envelope was created + viewed last week (April 27, 2022), and when the user tried to sign it today (May 4, 2022), they keep getting this error:

```json
DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiException: Error calling CreateRecipientView: {
    "errorCode":"UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT",
    "message":"The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope."
}
```

Note that hundreds of envelopes created before and after the above envelope are still able to obtain a recipient view with the exact same code + configuration. The problematic envelope has not expired, I can still see it in the *Waiting for Others* section of the DocuSign admin site. I have compared its recipient info at DocuSign (by invoking [ListRecipients](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/v2/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipients/list/)) with the info I have in my database, and the Name, Email, ClientUserId, RoleName, RoutingOrder all match completely. My account is set up to expire envelopes after 120 days, and I am not doing anything during envelope creation to set an expiration date. I have seen many others having this issue but typically their problem is the ClientUserId. My code has that handled, and it works for every other envelope.

The only difference I have seen between this envelope and the others is that *ListRecipients* results show the affected envelope as having a property

```json
"signatureInfo": {
    "fontStyle": "docusign7",
    "signatureInitials": "RW",
    "signatureName": "Test"
}
```

that is null for all other envelopes. The [documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/v2/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipients/list/#schema_200_recipients_recipients_signers_signatureinfo) states that this property can be set by the sender to pre-fill signature fields. However, I didn't even know about this property before today, so my app has never set it. It would be weird for this property to cause the envelope to be in a state where it cannot be signed anymore but I am struggling to find a reason why this particular envelope cannot be signed. Btw, the *signatureName* of Test actually matches the *Name* property of the recipient so its even more confusing why DocuSign is refusing to recognize the signer.

Comment: Please check the envelope that was created (it was still there in your developer account) and see what recipients it has. I wonder if this is a case where the template has different recipients, and while you try to match them with the roles, you still get a different one.

Comment: @InbarGazit the affected envelope is visible in the DocuSign admin site and I can query its recipient list, and all the relevant fields match my database (which I am using to create the recipient view request). Also, the affected envelope has exactly 1 recipient.

Comment: If you don't use a template - does this work ok?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by not using a template. I have edited my post to clarify that it is a problem with only 1 envelope. All the hundreds of envelopes before, and the few after, are working 100% correctly.

Comment: What is different about this one envelope?

Comment: It has a "signatureInfo" property set on it that none of the other envelopes do, and the documentation says I (the sender) would have pre-filled it ... except my code never does that. Despite that, the Name, Email and ClientUserId on the envelope appears to be identical to what I include in the recipient view request, so still not sure why I get the error.

Comment: Can you re-create it? or it was a one time thing that cannot be done again?

Comment: No, I have not been able to re-create it. What makes me nervous is that my code hasn't changed in a few months, yet this envelope was created last week. And my code is the only way to create envelopes in this account, so I would like to find out how it happened and how I can prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

If the envelope is still active, I suggest doing a Recipients:list operation.  Also check that the recipient is a "current" recipient. (If there's only one recipient, then this doesn't apply.)

If the Recipients:list doesn't give you any clues then I suggest you contact developer support. They can check our backend logs to see if there's additional information on why the RecipientsView call didn't work.

See page https://support.docusign.com/s/contactSupport?language=en_US First login to that page if you have a production account. You can get support if you only have a developer account.

Comment: When the envelope was active, I did invoke ListRecipients and all the user info matched what I had on my system. Unfortunately, the envelope is no longer active and I have not been able to reproduce this issue with any other envelope. Dropping this issue for now. Thank you to all who tried to help and asked questions.